# Define Permanent $scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So if in a lot of my controllers I have this:

```
$scope.error = false;
$scope.errorData = {};

$scope.working = false;
$scope.workingMessage = "Doing something, please wait..."; // best UI message ever
```

Is there a way of having these permanently defined on every `$scope` given to my controllers?

So I do need inheritence, so where can apply these scope variables to the `$rootScope` so that it will be picked up in all my controllers?

***Update***

So after much reading of the documentation, it appears that use `ngApp` auto bootstraps the angular app which is when the `$injector` service runs. I need to have the variables put on before this service runs, so I'm guessing that I need to manually bootstrap the application.

***More Work***

```
.run()
```

This runs after all the modules have been initialised. So here I can inject the $rootScope and put my variables on that. Then they can be used on my all my `$scope`s, obviously if you data bind to it then you can simply use the property names because the binder will first look at the `$scope` then all subsequent parent scopes until it finds the property.

```
.run(['$rootScope', rootScopeConfigure]);

function rootScopeConfigure($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.myCustomProperty = "Hey There";
}
```

As per a comment on my question, this can get dangerous if you are adding properties randomly. But as I have only a few properties, it doesn't really matter or add that much overhead. (I hope).

However, all this poses one problem, if I want to modify this custom property in the `controller` then I have to inject `$rootScope`. I don't particularly want to do this, I want to be able to access these on the `$scope`

In response to my above paragraph, I should be able to do `$scope.$root.myCustomProperty` because I'm guessing that the `$rootScope` is the root of all `$scope`s.

***Dirty Answer***

```
$rootScope.$oldNew = $rootScope.$new;

$rootScope.$new = function () {
   var childScope = $rootScope.$oldNew();
   childScope.myCustomerProp = "Hey There";

   return childScope;
}
```

Do this in the `run()` function. Basically overriding the factory to return a new child scope that has my property on it :).

Comment: You can put the variables that will be used in entire application to  `$rootScope` which is the parent scope of all scopes. But keep in mind it is not a good idea to pollute the rootScope with unnecessary stuff as it will be used in every part of application, this can cause performance problems and it will make your code more difficult to be traced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have the answer now.

`.run()`

This runs after all the modules have been initialised. So here I can inject the `$rootScope` override is `$new` function that I believe is just a simple scope factory.

Then any properties or methods put on that new scope can be used on my all my `$scope`s.

```
.run(['$rootScope', runtimeConfigure]);

function runtimeConfigure() {
    $rootScope.$oldNew = $rootScope.$new;

    $rootScope.$new = function(isolate, parent) {
        var child = $rootScope.$oldNew(isolate, parent);

        child.title = "Hey There";

        return child;
    }
}
```

I believe there to be no issues with doing this.

Firstly, I'm merely ghosting the original scope factory `$new`
Secondly, I'm just adding properties to the new scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, scopes can be inherited from parents. You can create a parent controller for your controllers.

A scope can inherit from a parent scope, as in this example:

```
var parent = $rootScope;
var child = parent.$new();

parent.salutation = "Hello";
child.name = "World";
expect(child.salutation).toEqual('Hello');

child.salutation = "Welcome";
expect(child.salutation).toEqual('Welcome');
expect(parent.salutation).toEqual('Hello');
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using scope but instead using $cacheFactory or a service/factory of your own to persist this type of state.

Comment: So, the idea is I can create my controller, and without having to define anything have these parameters ready to use. How does your answer address this, could you maybe post some sample code? Thanks for responding, much appreciated

Comment: Also, see my new edit with my dirty answer on it, could this cause problems?